# Process LockedOut status with Kentor/Owin

Tags: owin, kentor-authservices

I'm using the Kentor/SampleOwinApplication and I can successfully sign in and out from my Idp. Now I've made some tests with revoked users in the Asp.Net database. After successful federation signin and back into ExternalLoginCallback, SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync returns LockedOut and I land on the revoke page.

The problem is I'm not signed in for Asp.Net but I'm still for my Idp, so if I try to log in again, I'm considered already signed I am redirected instantly back to my service without the chance to try to log with another user.
I understand I would need to log out from my IDP when in the LockedOut status but it seems hard to do with Kentor because specifically I'm not signed in on the Asp.net site!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting border case!

What you should do is that when in the `ExternalLoginCallback` when you find out that you are locked out, you should kick of a federated logout by initiating a logout with the external identity as an argument. That will redirect the user to the Idp and invalidate the Idp session.

Note that this might have side effects if the user is already logged in to other services from the same Idp. Those other services will be logged out too.